# Joined 3 tables, not outputting all results from third table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:

```
Student - UPN, Name, Year, House

Seclusion_Status - ID, Arrived, FTE, Rebuild, DateTimeAdded, Staff, Student_UPN (fk), Comment

Period_Rating - ID, Slot_ID, Rating, Date, Seclusion_ID (fk)
```

Each student can have many entries in the Seclusion_Status table, and then there are also many entries in the Period_rating table, which is linked to the Seclusion_status table with the Seclusion_ID

I am running the following query to return a record from Seclusion_Status based on a date, and then all the records in the Period_rating table that relate to the Seclusion_status record.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Seclusion_Status 
      INNER JOIN Students ON Seclusion_Status.Student_UPN=Students.UPN 
      JOIN Period_Rating ON Seclusion_Status.ID=period_rating.Seclusion_ID
      WHERE period_rating.Date = '$start'
      GROUP BY period_rating.Seclusion_ID 
      ORDER BY Seclusion_Status.DateTimeAdded ASC";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
        // Start looping rows in mysql database.
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

The query is returning the Seclusion_Status record, and then the first record in Period_rating, but not the others.

```
 Array
[0] => 348
[ID] => 157
[1] => Y
[Arrived] => Y
[2] => N
[FTE] => N
[3] => 
[Rebuild] => 
[4] => 
[Text] => 
[5] => 2016-03-04 09:30:50
[DateTimeAdded] => 2016-03-04 09:30:50
[6] => Mr S Holland
[Staff] => Mr S Holland
[7] => K80222800
[Student_UPN] => K8022280
[8] => Refusing instructions
[Incident] => Refusing instructions
[9] =>  
[Period] =>  
[10] => 
[Period_In_ID] => 
[11] => Not sitting properly in class despite being asked
[Comment] => Not sitting properly in class despite being asked
[12] => K80222800
[UPN] => K80222800
[13] => Student Name
[Name] => Student Name
[14] => Year 9
[Year] => Year 9
[15] => Acer
[House] => Acer
[16] => 157
[17] => P2
[Slot_ID] => P2
[18] => 
[Rating] => 
[19] => 2016-03-04
[Date] => 2016-03-04
[20] => 348
[Seclusion_ID] => 348
[21] => 1
[Status] => 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The query is returning the Seclusion_Status record, and then the first record in Period_rating, but not the others.

You have a `GROUP BY period_rating.Seclusion_ID` that instructs mysql to return one record per Seclusion_ID. Take the group by clause out, and the query will return multiple records, that match.

Comment: Okay. I have removed that statement, and that sort of solves the issue. It is now returning all of the data. I am writing that data out in rows of a table, and need a separate row for each student, but then on the same row for that student all of the period_rating records. At the moment as it loops through, it is writing the same student on a separate row for each record in Period_rating.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a different question from the original. If this answer helped you to resolve your question, then pls accept the answer and ask any subsequent questions in their own topic!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is if you use join, if data is there in all the three tables then only it will fetch.

If you want to fetch all the entries in the table you need to use outer join, unfortunately u cant use outer join in mysql.

but you can fetch results by unioning leftjoin results and right join results

Comment: Left and right joins **are** outer joins. What mysql does not have is full outer join and you rightly wrote that it can be simulated via union and left/right joins.